# How to replace a part of a string before any specfic multi-character string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string

> "**40228-55 Port-ojons, Llc**   - (517) 652-2156 - example@domain.com"

**How can I use Javascript/Jquery to replace all the instances of "-" with spaces in the above string until the specific character**

I have tried preg replace, substring functions but didn't work.

- `str.replace(/-/g, ' ');`
- `str.substr(0, gdd2[1].indexOf('- ('))`

So, the expected output would be after the removal of all hyphens before that specific character -( phone-Number

"40228 55 **Port ojons**, Llc - (517) 652-2156 - example@domain.com"

Comment: Just remove the `/g` flag.

Comment: @the-fourth-bird, js regex and php regex are not the same :/

Comment: @Mars073 That is why I asked :), it is already updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to replace the first '-' with a space, you just need:

```
ur_string = ur_string.replace('-', ' ');
```

the "g" parameter in the regex means "global" and looks for any expression in the string

To replace a part of a string before any specfic character

```
let ur_string = "40228-55 Port-ojons, Llc - (517) 652-2156 - example@domain.com";
let split = ur_string.search(/\([0-9]{3}\)/);
ur_string = ur_string.substr(0, split).replace(/\-/g, ' ') + ur_string.substr(split);
```

Comment: Thanks, @mars073, what if I want to remove all the  instances of "-" until the specific character e.g **- (** (in the above sample string, while this number is dynamic.)

Comment: The following code looks for something like "(123)" in the string, pars the string in 2 parts, replace of all '-' in the first part and concat the result in the base string

`let ur_string = "40228-55 Port-ojons, Llc - (517) 652-2156 - example@domain.com";
let split = ur_string.search(/\([0-9]{3}\)/);
ur_string = ur_string.substr(0, split).replace(/\-/g, ' ') + ur_string.substr(split);`

Answer (score 1):

You may match all text up to the first occurrence of `- (` (with `/^.*?(?=- \()/`) and use an anonymous callback function:

```js
console.log(
  "40228-55 Port-ojons, Llc - (517) 652-2156 - example@domain.com".replace(/^.*?(?=- \()/, function(m) {
    return m.replace(/-/g, ' ');
  })
)
```

The `^.*?(?=- \()` matches the start of string with `^`, then matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible (wiht `.*?`) up to the first occurrence (but excluding it from the match) of `- (` (with `(?=- \()` lookahead). The `.replace(/-/g, ' ')` replaces all hyphens with a space in the matched text only.

With the latest ECMAScript enhancements you may also use the infinite width lookbehind feature:

```js
var s = "40228-55 Port-ojons, Llc - (517) 652-2156 - example@domain.com";
console.log(
  s.replace(/(?<!- \(.*?)-(?=.*- \()/gs, ' ')
)
```

The `(?<!- \(.*?)-(?=.*- \()` pattern matches any `-` that is not immediately preceded with `- (` and any other 0+ chars, and that is immediately followed with any 0+ chars as many as possible and then `- (`.

Currently, this is supported by Chrome and Node, please  refer to [ECMAScript 2016+ compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/).

Comment: sorry, his answer is doing what I needed.

Comment: @Kayani I only saw the `ur_string = ur_string.replace('-', ' ');` part of the answer for some reason.

Comment: just below the above part you can see the required answer

Comment: @Kayani Still, my answer is working as expected, too, and only involves 2 operations with no concatenation and splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `-` as string instead of regex, or just drop the `global flag (g)`

`g` flag is used when you want to replace all the instances of matching pattern, here you want to just replace the first so don't use `g` flag

```js
let str = "4022855 Port-ojons, Llc - (517) 652-2156 - example@domain.com"

console.log(str.replace('-',' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

`g` will replace all the occurrences. removing it will give you the expected result.

```js
console.log("4022855 Port-ojons, Llc - (517) 652-2156 - example@domain.com".replace("-", " "))
```